# Return position during d3 transition

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I have an element that moves from x=0 to x=100 in 5 second, with elastic easing.

```
d3.select(this).transition()
    .duration(5000)
    .ease('elastic')
    .attr("x",100);
```

Is there a way to return the element's position "frame-by-frame" over the course of this transition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually `attrTween` and cause side-effects while returning the correct values for transitioning attribute: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UKWrj/2/).

```js
d3.select(this).transition()
    .duration(5000)
    .ease('elastic')
    .attrTween('x', function (d, i, a) {
         return function (t) {
             var ip_value = d3.interpolate(a, 100)(t);
             sideEffect(ip_value);
             return ip_value;
         };
     });
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't produce the transition animation for me (http://jsfiddle.net/Amyunimus/UKWrj/1/)

Comment: `sideEffect` has to be the function you want to call. Replaced it by `console.log` in the demo and it works. Also, added the demo to the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see so `sideEffect` would be my position tracking function.